# Ruby on Rails - Controller without Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Iam new in Ruby on Rails. Normally I work with other web languages and now (of course) I try to compare it with other languages using on web.

But sometimes i have some problem to understand the philosophy and the character of Ruby on Rails. Of course i understand the concept of MVC.

But now Iam not absolutely sure: 
Is ist OK to create and use a controller without views? In some cases you need a "class" for some usefull functionality used by other controllers they have views. Or is it a better style to use a module?

I try to find it out by reading a lot of articles and examples, but didnt find detailed information about this content.

Comment: no, if it doesn't need view, it doesn't need to be placed in controller, it should be done inside model

Comment: you could also make new class/module libs and load them if you need custom logic that is not tied to ActiveRecord

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Controller handles request and renders corresponding view template. So controller without view is absolutely nonsense.

Every time request will execute this controller, it will just end with missing template error, so you will need to create view folder and put empty files with action name inside of it, which is obviously stupid.

Comment: Clear statement. THX :)

Comment: not necessarily; you could have `render nothing: true` at the end of the action and have no file in the view folder

Comment: You could want to serve different applications with your controllers, one where you use your views and one where you serve different client applications with JSON data only for example. Rails won't complain if you don't have views in this scenarion as long as you use `render json:`, but it will crash if you use `render status: :no_content`. When you don't need to return content to a request you have to use `head :no_content`, for example

Answer (score 3):

When developing Ruby On Rails apps, it's recommended to put most of your business logic in the **models**, so for the controllers the logic need to be **minimal** to provide info for the views, so if it doesn't work with a view chance that you need a controller are really low.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it OK to create and use a controller without views

Yep it's okay.

The key thing to keep in mind is that Ruby/Rails is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

This means that every single you do with your controllers/models etc should have the "object" you're manipulating at its core.

With this in mind, it means you can have a controller without corresponding views, as sometimes, you just need to manipulate an object and return a simple response (for example with Ajax).

--

We often re-use views for different actions (does that count as not having a view):

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def search
      render :index, layout: false
   end
end
```

---

The notion of [`skinny controller, fat model`](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) is sound in principle, you have to account for the times when you may need small pieces of functionality that can *only* be handled by a controller:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def update
      @user = User.find params[:id]
      @user.update
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render nothing: true}
        format.html
      end
   end
end
```

---

A very rudimentary example of Rails is a drive-thru:

- `view` = input interface
- `controller` = accepts order & delivers
- `model` = gets order packaged etc in backend

There are times when the controller may not need a view (for example, if you update your order with specific dietry requirements), and thus the notion that every controller action has to have a view is false.

It's really about making your controller versatile enough to manage your objects correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Shared controller methods can be placed in ApplicationController. Also, in Rails 4 there are concerns (app/controllers/concerns/) where you can put the modules with methods that can be used by multiple controllers.